# React Router Match with Params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So most of the examples of param matching I found has the same pattern. 
Inside

```
const TopicDetail = ({ match }) => {
```

This works fine on getting match then accessing the id by {match.params.topicId} for example.

I have a full class set up on this page so it looks more like this

```
class main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
```

and App.js like this

```
<Route path="/:type" component={main} />
```

and if I enter the match inside render({match}) then attempt to access {match.params.type}, I get an error.

How can I achieve to accept match inside my class? Do I need to have a constant outside of my class then pull in the const value? If so can someone post a working example?

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

Comment: instead of `render({match}) ` use `render () { let {match} = this.props;  return (....) }`

Comment: you need to access using `this.props.match.param.type`, or destructure the props inside render method, like this: `render() {const { match } = this.props; return (....)}` and access by `match.params.type`.

Comment: I did `console.log(this.props.match.param.type)` got an error

Comment: `const { match } = this.props; return (....)
    console.log(match.params.type)` this is not working either...

Comment: what is the result of `console.log(match.params.type)`

Comment: It wont log, there's a parsing error if I do `render() {const { match } = this.props; return (....)}` and access by `match.params.type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, for class based component destructuring is done inside the method.

eg:

```
render() {
      let { match } = this.props;
      return (.....)
}
```

Comment: I get below error `./src/components/Pages/main.js
  Line 41:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  39 |   render() {
  40 |     let { match } = this.props;
> 41 |       return (.....)`

Comment: use `render () { let match; ({match} = this.props); return (...)}`

Comment: okay below code works, `  render () { 
  let match; ({match} = this.props); 
  console.log(match.params.type)` Thank you @JS Engine

Comment: However, just so everyone knows, I prefer this better since I have other const's for this.props, I just added match to that list..  like this `const {match} = this.props; console.log(match.params.type)` and when I added them to my props it looks like this  `const { classes, match } = this.props;console.log(match.params.type)`